# Any XML editor that renders xml without angular braces - with strong emphasis on indentation

Tags: xml

I am looking for an XML editor that has view that removes those ugly braces and double tags and renders XML in Python like style, is there anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

Use any text editor which has so detailed colour scheme adjusting that it allows you to change the colour of the angle brackets. Then set them to match the background colour. Slightly hackish but works.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it ANGLES will not have brackets: https://github.com/umd-mith/angles

I'm working on an editor but it's in the early stages of development. Here's a screenshot:

[image: ss of app]